# certificate-generator.sh file is missing in tizen sdk installed on mac

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-emulator

> I have installed Samsung Tizen TV SDK 1.5 on my mac machine. To set
>   active secure profile I need certificate-generator.sh file, but it is
>   missing in path as mentioned in following link
>   https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/Set_Active_Secure_Profile

Above issue was only present in Samsung Tizen TV SDK 1.5. But now 2.0 version is available and there is no such issue in updated sdk. So Closing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the separate sdk's plugin from Samsung ?

see bottom of :

https://developer.tizen.org/downloads/tizen-sdk

```
If you would like to test your appplication on a real Tizen device,
then you would need to install some extensions.
For more information on Tizen devices, visit:
```

http://developer.tizen.org/devices

Extra hints :

- https://developer.tizen.org/trouble-shooting-certification
- https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/SDK

Comment: I am not able to open any link.